# Find a matrix-valued product, given the eigenvalues and eigenspaces of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> $M$ is a matrix, $3\times 3$. The space of the eigenvalue $-2$ is $\{(0; t; s) : t; s \in \mathbb{R}\}$ and the space of the eigenvalue $5$ is $\{(0; t; s) : t; s \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Then they ask the value of

$$M\begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\\-2\end{pmatrix}$$ 
I've tried using the formula: $A = P D P^{-1}$

P being
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
         0 & 0 & 1 \\
         1 & 0 & 0 \\
         0 & 1 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

And $D$ being 
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        -2 & 0 & 0 \\
         0 & -2 & 0 \\
         0 & 0 & 5 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

But it gets me nowhere near the solution which is the vector $(5, -2, 4)$

Comment: funny character? the { ? @mvw

Comment: Do you mean $$M\begin{bmatrix}{1\\ 1\\ -2}\end{bmatrix}?$$

Comment: Something is off with the question: the eigenspace of $-2$ and the eigenspace of $5$ cannot be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenspaces of $-2$ and $5$ are non-empty and coincide, which is not possible. Judging from your matrix $P$ I guess that the eigespace of $5$ is actually $\{(r,0,0) \mid r \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Then we already have all we need: We have $M = P D P^{-1}$ for the matrices
$$
P =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 1 \\
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
 \end{pmatrix}
\quad\text{and}\quad
 \begin{pmatrix}
  -2 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & -2 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 5 \\
 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Because $P^{-1}$ is given by
$$
P^{-1} =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 \\
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
we get that
$$
 M \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ -2 \end{pmatrix}
= PDP^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ -2 \end{pmatrix}
= PD \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
= P \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 4 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ -2 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

If Jendrik's assumption is correct, observe that
$$\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 1\\ -2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\\ -2\end{pmatrix},
$$
hence its image under $M$ is 
$$5\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}-2\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\\ -2\end{pmatrix}.$$